# Multiple reposistories in git repository

Tags: git, magento, github, git-submodules

Can I create a multiple repos git repo for store magento modules with submodule? For example:

```
modules (master)
|_module1 (master) // submodule
|_module2 (master) // submodule
```

Then, can I version and update separated each other? For Example, I have to use module2 in a project and I clone it by itself?

The main point is, I want to store a lot of magento modules on github in one repository, but separated.

Thank you!

Comment: You'll have to create a remote repository for each submodule which kinda destroys the purpose of this idea.